# Python xlwt - Convert column integer into excel cell references. Eg (3,6) to C6

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I'm automating formula's using pythons XLWT library.  I have column indexs, eg, 1,2,3,99, etc and would like to convert to A,B,C,D, AA,AB, etc.

Is there anything built into xlwt for this? Or should I just write my own function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `xlrd`s helper function:

```
import xlrd
print xlrd.colname(56)
# BE
```

Strangely - there doesn't appear to be a direct equivalent in `xlwt` or `xlwt.Utils` (although this does have various helper functions for conversion of cells and names)

Going by the question's title - you can use:

```
>>> xlwt.Utils.rowcol_to_cell(5, 2)
'C6'
```

Comment: Brilliant!  I search all through the source and docs of xlwt, but didn't think to look in xlrd.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @Humphrey I noticed that the question in the title is slightly different - so I've updated the answer to include `xlwt.Utils.rowcol_to_cell` which produces the full cell address